# How to deal with stubborn players?

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic, problem-players

Okay, so my problem is that one of the people I have in my party (my brother) is **VERY** stubborn when it comes to playing a session of D&D, everything from getting on his tablet and getting distracted to the point where when it's his turn he has no clue what is even happening, saying things like "I punch the monster" when it is 50 feet away from him. I tried to incite a tabletop rule of "No electronics" but everytime I tell him to put his tablet away, he labels me a "Tight-ass DM" and tells me its my fault no one is having fun. What can I do about this? Is he right? Should I make changes to adhere to his rules? I have contemplated removing him from the game, but I really don't want to as he is my brother.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! If your question is different enough from [this one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33948/4398) that its answers can't help you, please edit this question to highlight the details of your particular situation that you need addressed.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when he's angry he constantly talks about how he doesn't like the game as it is "Unrealistic and stupid", but strangely enough, he doesn't want to stop playing. I've told him he will have to stop playing until he can straighten himself out, so maybe that will change his mind. Otherwise, someone else will have to take on his character, as well as theirs. @BESW I have already looked there for an answer, but thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: Don't answer in comments.

Comment: Closing as duplicate for the time being.  Is your problem really different, or just that you don't like the existing answers? The solution to that is to go bump that question (I know you don't have enough rep to bounty it yet) to get better answers there...  If it's different you'll need to explain why more.

Answer (score 0):

Is no one having fun, like he says, or is it just him?

If he's not having fun, why is he still playing?

You need to talk to him about whether or not he is really interested in playing in your game or not. Maybe he just wants to be there to hang out with friends, and could just spectate.

Comment: They usually are frustrated that he is bringing the game down and they wish they could continue, but as I said, he just doesn't seem to be cooperative. I'm going to remove him from the game and see if that makes the game any more fun for everyone, and honestly, I think most it likely will as there would be only players who actually try then.