# What should I do if a player never seems interested and always in a rush, always ruining the mood of the game?

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players, group-dynamics

I am currently in a campaign with 4 other party members, this is all of our first campaigns playing except for the DM who has done a few other campaigns, we are a happy go lucky just fun group since it is our first campaign and our DM takes it easy on us, letting us get better gear than we honestly should have at this point in time, trying to make it as fun as possible for us, he puts in a ton of time into the campaign to make it more enjoyable and I really appreciate him. The issue is, whenever we play, we have one party member who **always seems to just not be interested and is always on their phone, sulking and always in a rush, we will call them Cleric(since that is their role) it's not in such a matter that they don't just enjoy certain parts of the game, they simply sulk the whole time and get mad at seemingly nothing. We also cannot simply remove them from the group since they are in a relationship with one of the other players that actually add a lot to our party and makes the game more fun too.**

For example, on our second session, we finally went into a dungeon, and when we got in, we all split into our separate paths, except for Cleric, they simply said I follow the ranger the whole time, and went back onto their phone and when asked for if they wanted to do anything any time they just said no and kept looking at their phone. This was okay, because it could honestly fit into their character. Where this got bad was when the DM set a trap for us in a room, it made me turn into a mimic of sorts, basically an evil spirit took over my body and I was to try and tpk basically. When I finally made my move, combat ensued in a 1v3 with me versus 2 npcs and our warrior. During this battle, Cleric seemed very irritated that we were the only ones having battle and that they couldn't just meta game and tell our ranger to go to the other side of the dungeon, we were also about 200 feet away so they were also upset their Tabaxi Keen Senses weren't telling them anything. After that got vetod they decided to sulk the rest of the time and opted out of any conversation or actions and just followed.

Next session the same thing happened, we ended up accidentally messing up the DM's plans and kind of agrod the BBEG, but hey that's okay. Except a bunch of dialogue happened and during it, Cleric decided to say they go sit in a corner and got on their phone. When combat started happening(they sent a shadow teleporter rogue multicalssed into monk on us), I had to use my dancing lights cantrip to try and save everyone from being able to be sneak attacked since we made shadows as well. We all(who were in the room) were attempting to fight the enemy, we had to role initiative, and without looking off their phone, Cleric rolls and sulks since they go last, and when it was their turn to go, they decided to just leave and never cast a spell or do anything at all to help.

After this, Cleric was gone, and me any our warrior killed the rogue(this was crazy because if I didn't have dancing lights we probably would have died), we found a room of gold(the DM was trying to taunt us) and Cleric decided that they wanted to come back to get some gold, even though they had already left the dungeon completely and would have no clue of the room, but found an excuse to go back in, only to grab a sapphire and gold and then leave. Meanwhile I wild shaped into a draft horse(500lb carry weight) and since I had purchased saddle bags for my when I am wild shaped so I could be out pack mule, the warrior and I loaded up all the gold in the room, making the DM look like a fool, and took the gold, well when we got out, Cleric decided to say they should get some of the gold since they were in the dungeon and "helped load it" even though they only took a sapphire and left, when I said no, they decided to sulk and say nothing the rest of the session.

This led to our current session(where Cleric was already upset when they came in) we went back to town and got magic items from that gold room, which I gave the cleric the item that the DM wanted to give them from the dungeon, there was an item for each person in the party, and we all had no clue what we were supposed to do with them so we had to go to an enchanter to see. We all did so, except the Cleric who angrily said I don't want to spend any more time so we can just make this quick, even though it would take 20 seconds to do so. Well, I took the bag of gems I got from the gold room last session, and exchanged all the gems into diamonds worth 300g so that I could give them to the cleric, I told them that they should keep these and use them for revival and they should get the spell when they could, so they just didn't respond, stayed on their phone, and didn't even mark down the diamonds on their inventory.

We then got to leave port and we ended up fighting a dragon on the way to our next dungeon, well the DM did a really good job of making it seem like we were just gonna die instantly, and introducing the dragon, except the ship by the time the dragon got there already did half of it's health, and the DM was trying to not kill us but make us fight the dragon, except cleric was sulking and getting mad since we were going to have to fight the dragon, even though the time was only 8PM and they told us they could be there until 10 that night, they completely ruined the fight by sulking and being mad the whole time.

Our DM is doing a great job at making it enjoyable for new players and in general spicing it up with fun magic items and enemies we specifically hunt down, except Cleric just ruins the mood the whole time and is putting a huge damper on the whole game even though everyone else is engaging and having fun, but when it gets to their turn we all just feel the negativity and just don't have fun anymore.

I do not know what to do here, and neither does our DM since I talked to them about this, and they feel the same way, but we don't know what to do here, and we cannot simply kick them out of the campaign for other reasons. What should the DM or I try to do here?

Comment: Welcome to our stack, rexpi! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate as a site and you can visit the [help] for more information, too.

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate currently because I think your issue is the same as a previous asker. If that Q&A isn't helpful, can you clarify what's different with yours? A duplicate is not a bad thing or a problem - it's another way for others to find similar issues :)

Comment: Sure, I do see how it could be a similar issue to the form you discussed, the issue with theirs is they are unengaged other than delving into a dungeon and actively participates in their campaign, the Cleric in this story simply ruins the mood during anything, it brings down the DM and makes it so it's not very enjoyable for anyone in any situation, we can deal with the non-engagement of them, it's the morale of the party and the DM as well since DND does very much deal with the vibe and feeling of the campaign

Comment: @rexpi I've added another link to the dupe header, about a question specifically about dealing with a player who is constantly on their phone. Let us know if that doesnt focus more on your problem: [A player constantly uses his mobile phone during our game session](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67831)

Comment: Ill go ahead and check it out, Thank you! I went ahead and checked out a few things on there, I'll see how it goes, we are meeting again soon, I just want the DM's hard work to not go to waste since he is doing a great job on the campaign and the Cleric simply brings down the mood the whole time.

Comment: The linked questions are about a player distracted by their phone, and a player refusing to roleplay yet being active on the mechanical side of the game and attempting to steer the game OOC (poorly).  This question is about a player who gets angry when their ideas are vetoed (tabaxi racial traits not instantly noticing far off noises) and passive-aggressively refuses to participate IC or OOC.  Seems very different to me, so i've voted to re-open.  Specifically, the answers to the other questions do not seem to apply to this one which is a more outright negative situation.

Comment: I just want the DM's hard work to not go to waste since he is doing a great job on the campaign and **the Cleric simply brings down the mood the whole time** How many fellow players have told this player that simple thing?

Comment: Have the other questions helped you? I think this could be separate enough to reopen but there is no need if the other links have given you what you need.

Comment: None of the answers on the other thread outright would solve the issue in my opinion but some of them would be worth a shot at seeing if it would work. I'm going to try seeing what I could do with the advice that was given on the other threads and if it doesn't help I'll add some edits and try to vote for re-open. Thank you all though!